# Using Github repo's in LIght Table

Tags: github, clojure

Is there a way to use or 'import' Github clojure-projects in LightTable?

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I tried something with leiningen but it gives me an error:

```
can not find C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg
```

actually, the real path is

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg
```

what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Modify your environment variable `%JAVA_HOME%` to

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\
```

And it should do the trick.

About importing Github projects, I don't know what you're talking about...